# CSS3 - Auto collapsing DIV based on media query

Tags: css

**Scenario:**

---

Note: I am trying to do this completely through CSS3 without using any Javascript / JQuery / etc. The solution to the problem needs to be purely in CSS (no scripts please !!!)

---

The screen layout is a Header + 2 column layout. The header has the site title, etc. The left-hand column is set to about 25% of the screen width and contains a set of menus. The right-hand column is the rest of the screen and contains the "content" of the page.

When the screen width is > 700px, the layout is as above (header + 2 columns).

But when the screen width is < 700px, the layout is supposed to change to a single column. Here, the order would be Header, then the menu and then the content.

The menu itself has an expand/collapse action through an Expander implementation. What is supposed to happen is that when the screen is being resized from > 700px to < 700px (i.e., when the layout changes), the menus are supposed to collapse.

**Issue:**

The problem is when I try to collapse the menus in my media query, the menus never expand again because the media query is forcing the attributes to stay put ! Expand/Collapse happens through setting or removing the "display: none;" attribute.

Pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to avoid setting the display property directly (which I assume you do with JS - you didn't explain what you mean with "Expander implementation"). Instead, toggle a classname on the menu, and scope the styling for that with a media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
    .menu.disabled {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you said above is kind of what I tried to do. What happens is that the object stays permanently hidden. I guess it is because of the media query. I checked this with the console on both Google Chrome and IE, and the computed property stays "display: none;" after this has been done.

Comment: Well, if the media query is constructed correctly, it should never be applied for screen sizes of 700 px wide and up. Also, remember that media queries themselves don't affect specificity, but participate in the cascade, so order and selector weight matters. If you can't figure it out, put up a code example.